# naming conventions of Controller and Model Java classes in Spring / MVC webapp?

Tags: java, web-applications, spring-mvc

Let's say I have "settings" classes in my controllers and models, in my Java/Spring/MVC webapp. Now, in both `/controllers/` and `/models/`, should I...

1) ...name them both `Settings.java`?

2) ...name them `SettingsController.java` and `SettingsModel.java` or something similar?

I'm curious about typical naming conventions as well as naming conventions used in your personal experience that worked well. Feel free to reference your own webapp project in place of my, perhaps poor, example.

This is my first MVC webapp, and I'm trying to get a feel for it.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I'd suggest you to call your controller `SettingsController` and model just `Settings`. It is because model actually contains you data. What kind of data does your model contain? The answer is: settings. So, call it settings.

Controller is different story. It is a class that deals with you data. There are probably many classes that deal with settings: `SettingsBuilder`, `SettingsFactory`, `SettingsUtil`, `SettingsService` etc. This one is controller, so call it `SettingsController`.

Answer (score 7):

Since model classses describe 'real-life' entities it's better to call them by name, so in your case it would be `Settings.java`.

Controller, on the other hand, is just a byproduct of using specific architecture (MVC) so it gets the `Controller` suffix, and in your case becomes `SettingsController.java`.

If you did your application using jsf, for example, you could still have `Settings.java` as model, but `SettingsBean.java` as a controller (obviously that's just another convention and you could call it however you like).

Answer (score 3):

Name them `SettingsController.java` and `Settings.java`

Answer (score 2):

I'd opt for Settings.java and SettingsController.java.

*Controller follows Spring's convention of controller naming. Furthermore it lets the programmer understand immediately what the class does.

Generally I always plump for simple names for POJO's, Settings.java seems to fit the bill here.

Answer (score 1):

I think the following style is most coherent

```
com.company.web.controller
               +-  SettingsController.java
com.company.web.model
               +-  Settings.java
```

The reason is that `Settings` is a name describing exactly what it is, while `SettingsController` describes that it's a controller working on `Settings` objects.

Comment: I agree with your naming, but disagree with the package structure - I'd have them both in the same package, or at least under the same package tree. But that may be a matter of preference as well.

Comment: @RobHruska we have it set the same way, with `com.subdomainname.controllers` and `com.subdomainname.models`, and this is the structure the company I work for uses, so I have to follow along.

Answer (score 1):

I have to agree with the previous posters, Model should just be the name of the entity, and then anything that adjective should be a suffix of the entity, so Settings and SettingsController This is the tact  I take quite often.  I also use settings as the name of the webpage as well.

Answer (score 0):

I would use

`com.company.controller.SettingsServlet.java` for the controller and `com.company.model.Settings.java` for the model class.

You can indicate the controller aspect of the Controller class using the package naming `com.company.controller` but it is a Servlet after all and will be unmistakable as anything else with this naming. A controller could technically be anything of any type. The model class is also indicated by it's package name.

To Follow by faith alone is to follow blindly - Benjamin Franklin